# Which sorting algorithm is behind an NSSortDescriptor?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nssortdescriptor

Is that thing using bubble sort? Or what exactly? How does it work in context with an NSFetchRequest of Core Data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The `NSSortDescriptor` API does not
   specify the algorithm (or even, like
   virtually all of the Cocoa APIs, a
   Big-O complexity guarantee). You
   should assume that the sort
   algorithm used is an implementation
   detail. You should probably also
   assume, however, that the algorithm
   used is selected at run time for
   best performance. Unless you have
   hard requirements for time or memory
   complexity, you should use the
   public API and let the framework
   authors at Apple worry abou the
   details.

   If you have complexity requirements,
   you may find [CHDataStructures](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures)
   framework helpful in writing your
   own collection/sorting
   implementation.
2. For `NSFetchRequest`, you should again assume that it is choosing an appropriate sort algorithm. In particular, sorting will be done by the SQLite engine, if possible, when using a SQL persistent store with Core Data.